# theme_table drupal development

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-7

## update

I have made this table: I have 2 array's UGentArray and InternshipsArray. How can I set these in my table? instead of "Row column 1 data" and "Row column 2 data". My question is: I want the values from UgentArray and InternshipArray as 2 columns under Each title UGentID and Internships

```
enter code here// Make table and display on screen.
$tbl_header = array();
$tbl_header[] = array("data" => "UGentID");
$tbl_header[] = array("data" => "Internships");
$tbl_row = array();    
foreach($studentUGentID as $key => $value) {
    for($i = 0; $i<count($value); $i++) {
        $tbl_row[] = $value[$i]['value'];
    }
}
$tbl_row[] = "Row column 2 data";
$tbl_rows = array();
$tbl_rows[] = $tbl_row;    
$html = theme_table($tbl_header,$tbl_rows);
return $html;![enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but a general comment. Instead of calling `theme_table`, you should call `theme('table', ...` instead. ie. `theme('table', $tbl_header, $tbl_rows)` in your example above.

Comment: Indeed the output, seems a little better now. I followed this example: http://chooch.net/user/21/drupal-themetable-example . Thanks for your helpfull reply anyway!

Comment: If you want I can migrate to drupal.SE; you might get more hits over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having an example of the data you are starting with it is difficult to give you exact code to solve your problem.

In general the best way to built tables in Drupal is like this:

```
$table_headers = array(
  t('UGentID'), // this is the header for the first column
  t('Internships'), // this is the header for the second column
);
$table_rows = array()
foreach ($studentUGentID as $key => $value) {
  $table_rows[] = array(
    'column 1 data', // add all the data for the row one column
    'column 2 data', // at a time
  );
}
$html = theme('table', $table_headers, $table_rows);
```

As I said without knowing what is in `$studentUGentID` and `$internships` I cannot help further.

With sample data I could help you more.